# Can elements/entries in sequence be different type? $a,(a,b),(a,b,c),(a,b,c,d),\ldots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions

I am wondering if this could be a sequence, eg

$$a,(a,b),(a,b,c),(a,b,c,d),\ldots$$

Generally, I think it could, depending on how you create them. But from a formal definition as a function, you cannot have a such function to produce the outcome with different type of elements

Comment: A sequence is a map from $\Bbb N$ to a set $E,$ and  $E$ can contain anything you want. E.g. $E=\cup_{n\in\Bbb N}A^n$ where $A$ is your alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set $X$ a sequence $a$ in $X$ is taken as a function $a:\mathbb N\to X$. Simply choose your $X$ to contain whatever you need. Note that in mathematics we do not have a strict concept of "type", and a set may contain any object, as long we do not break the basic axioms of set theory.